# Writing python dictionary items into separate txt files

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have dictionary (which is generated each time) that looks like this:

```
{'Module1': [], 'Module2':['C:\\folder1\\folder2\\Module2\\Module2.1.c', 'C:\\folder1\\folder2\\Module2\\Module2.2.c', 'C:\\folder1\\folder2\\Module2\\Module2.3.c',  'Module3': ['C:\\folder1\\folder2\\Module3\\Module3.1.c', 'C:\\folder1\\folder2\\Module3\\Module3.2.c'], 'Module4': ['C:\\folder1\\folder2\\Module4\\Module4.1.c', 'C:\\folder1\\folder2\\Module4\\Module4.2.c', etc
```

So it contains names of the modules and paths to it's .c files inside.

What would be the best approach to make separate txt files for each of them which contains only those paths?

So for an example I should have: Module1.txt which will be empty, then Module2.txt which will contain:

```
'C:\folder1\folder2\Module2\Module2.1.c'
'C:\folder1\folder2\Module2\Module2.2.c'
'C:\folder1\folder2\Module2\Module2.3.c'
```

Comment: Best approach: Write a function that writes one file, then call that function in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

data = {
    'Module1': [],
    'Module2': ['C:\\folder1\\folder2\\Module2\\Module2.1.c',
        'C:\\folder1\\folder2\\Module2\\Module2.2.c',
        'C:\\folder1\\folder2\\Module2\\Module2.3.c'],
    'Module3': ['C:\\folder1\\folder2\\Module3\\Module3.1.c',
        'C:\\folder1\\folder2\\Module3\\Module3.2.c'],
    'Module4': ['C:\\folder1\\folder2\\Module4\\Module4.1.c',
        'C:\\folder1\\folder2\\Module4\\Module4.2.c']
}

def handleModule(filename, data):
    data = ["'%s'" % item for item in data]
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write(' '.join(data))

for filename, module in data.items():
    handleModule(filename, module)
```

In the main loop we are going through all the keys and values of the dictionary. For every key/value pair (filename/module) handleModule is called.

There is a list comprehension at the beginning of handleModule function: `["'%s'" % item for item in data]`. It adds quotes to every list item.

We open file: `with open(filename, 'w') as f:`. It does the same thing as `f = open(filename, 'w')` but guaranties file closing after the end of the block.

`' '.join(data)` joins all items in the list into a string, using a space character as separator. This string we write to the file.